Rear shifter cable wont stay in anything but the highest gear
I'm a beginner and I have just bought a Kona sutra, everything was going fine until yesterday when the rear shifter cable developed a problem. When I try to shift up into higher gears it just kicks me straight back down.
The derailleur is a Shimano deore and I've tried adjusting the tension with the barrel adjuster and it seems ok but it just won't hold anything above the smallest cogs. The high and low set also seem fine but I don't understand why the tension in the cable is just pulling it straight back to the smallest cog, could it be overstretched?

Does the shifter have a "gear indicator" of some sort (little window with a red line that moves when you shift, possibly with numbers)?
If yes, does the indicator move back to the highest gear as well, or does the shifter behave "normally"?
If the shifter behaves as expected, but no actual gear shifts happen, the shift cable might be broken, or the cable clamp on the derailleur might be loose. In this case, tighten the clamp or change the cable.
If the shifter is unable to hold the tension, either something internally could be broken, or some grease in the shifter could have hardened, preventing the pawls that are supposed to hold the tension from engaging properly. The hardened grease can be washed out with e.g. WD40.

I take it as you mean you can't shift into lower gears in the rear (i.e you can't move to larger cogs as the deraileur just slips back). I also understand it as you are able to shift down (one or more cogs) but it drops back to the smallest cog almost immediately afterwards.
It sounds like you have some problem within the shifter itself as it fails to hold the cable in its place after making a shift.

I'm pretty sure your Kona Sutra has 'bar-end' gear shifters. If so, does the one on the right (for the rear gears) click from position to position, or slide smoothly? Most bar-end gear shifters allow you to choose "indexed" (or "SIS") mode, where the lever clicks from one gear to the next; or "friction" mode, where there are no clicks and you can fine-tune the derailleur position with small movements of the lever.
If it's in "friction" mode then the M5 screw at the lever pivot probably just needs to be tightened up so there's enough friction to resist the derailleur's return spring.
If it's in "indexed" mode then there's something else amiss, and your probelm is not something I've come across before.
